# how to detect the scroll reaches the specific component in react js using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can we identify onScoll event reaches a specific component? I have tried to use ref to scrollinto view thats works when we fire click event. But how it works user scroll down and reaches specific component, that time i should perform some task. how can we achive that?

```
 import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const eipCard = useRef(null);
  const salaryCard = useRef(null);
  const salesCard = useRef(null);

  const handleStickyHeader = () => {
     //handle logic

    // should trigger scroll reaches eip card
    console.log("reaches eip card")
    // should trigger scroll reaches salary card
    console.log("reaches salary card")
    // should trigger scroll reaches sales card
    console.log("reaches sales card")
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleStickyHeader);
    }
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleStickyHeader);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        ref={eipCard}
        style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
      ></div>
      <div
        ref={salaryCard}
        style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
      ></div>
      <div
        ref={salesCard}
        style={{ height: "500px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: have you tried this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-in-viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to create custom React hooks checking components in view.
Here is the working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mbi53f?file=useIntersectionObserver.ts)